# How can I add multiple reviewers using Bitbucket rest api?

Tags: json, api, bitbucket, pull-request, bitbucket-api

At the moment I am using a json file that i send with curl, but i am only able to add one reviewer.

```
  "locked": false,
    "reviewers": [
        {
            "user": {
                "name": "charlie"
            }
        }
    ],
```

I just want to add more different users. for example Charlie and Patrick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  "locked": false,
    "reviewers": [
        {
            "user": {
                "name": "charlie"
            },
            "user": {
                "name": "your name "
            },
            "user": {
                "name": "Patrick"
            }
        }
    ],
```

Like this work for me

Answer (score -1):

For me works solution like that:

```
  "locked": false,
    "reviewers": [
        {
            "user": {
                "name": "user_1"
            }
        },
        {
            "user": {
                "name": "user_2"
            }
        },
        {
            "user": {
                "name": "user_3"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: That was for older BitBucket version.